# Java FileChannel with ByteBuffer in Clojure?

Tags: java, performance, file, clojure

I want to use the following code in Clojure to quickly read a file into memory:

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream( name );
FileChannel ch = f.getChannel( );
byte[] barray = new byte[SIZE];
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap( barray );
long checkSum = 0L;
int nRead;

while ((nRead = ch.read(bb)) != -1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nRead; i++)
        checkSum += barray[i];

    bb.clear( );
}
```

Code from: [FileChannel with array ByteBuffer and byte array access](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly)

Calling the Java class constructors and dot-methods is straightforward enough, but will using Clojure's `while` and `for` cause a significant performance penalty? Is there anything wrong with just trying to convert Clojure the most direct way?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use `dotimes` instead of `for` and `loop..recur` instead of `while`.

However if you are really after performance, instead of reading, I would memory-map the `FileChannel` and create a `LongBuffer` from the `ByteBuffer` so as to read bytes eight by eight.

Comment: Thank you for your comments about the `dotimes` and `loop..recur`. Good reminders. On using memory mapping the `FileChannel`, do you have a reference for how to do this? And do you mean using `MappedByteBuffer`?

Comment: Yes a MappedByteBuffer as returned by http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long) and then call asLongBuffer (and perform some bit fiddling to access individual bytes).